# Как отправить сообщение процессу запущенному через spawn?

Tags: node.js

Нужно отправить сообщение процессу который запущен через spawn.

```
const prcs = spawn('node', [
    path_,
    `--url=${url}`,
], {});
prcs.stdout.on('data', (stdout) => {

    prcs.send({
        prop1: 100
    });
})
```

Но выводится ошибка

> prcs.send({
>
> TypeError: prcs.send is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы иметь возможность отправлять сообщения необходимо использовать `fork` вместо `spawn`

> The child_process.fork() method is a special case of child_process.spawn() used specifically to spawn new Node.js processes. Like child_process.spawn(), a ChildProcess object is returned. The returned ChildProcess will have an additional communication channel built-in that allows messages to be passed back and forth between the parent and child. See subprocess.send() for details.

Так что в итоге это будет так:

```
// master.js
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const { fork } = require('child_process');

const prcs = fork(path.join(__dirname, './slave.js'));

prcs.on('message', msg => {
  console.log('SLAVE is saying:', msg);
});

prcs.send('DO IT!!!');

// slave.js
'use strict';

process.on('message', msg => {
  console.log('PARENT is saying:', msg);
});

setTimeout(() => {
  process.send('Let me free please');
  process.exit(0);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: А для spawn это как то можно сделать?

Comment: судя по документации - никак, но вообще все зависит от того что ты хочешь сделать, если просто передать какой то параметр то можно через `env` но bidirectional общение так не получится организовать

Comment: Мне нужно завершить child процесс. 
Он передал данные, я их получил и дальше мне надо завершить этот процесс. 

Вот так правильно?
**myChildProcess.stdin.pause();
          myChildProcess.kill();**

Comment: скопируйте мой кусочек кода и проверьте, но на сколько я помню вы должны отправить из родителя какое то сообщение и только при этом сообщении fork может "самозавершиться"

Comment: Нет, не при fork, а при spawn. При fork используется ведь тот же исполняемый node.js что и у родителя?

Comment: Изначально вам нужно было общаться между процессами, и это возможно только при `fork`, что то изменилось? если да то обновите вопрос или откройте новый, думаю так всем будет понятнее (подумайте о тех кто найдет этот вопрос-ответ, им должно быть все понятно)